# Flutter Run stuck on "Launching"

Tags: flutter, macos, dart

I'm trying to launch a flutter application for the first time but it is unable to start.

I tried to use "Flutter run" and I expected the application to start but it ends up stuck on "Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode..."

I ran flutter doctor and everything is all set with no issues. I also tried to create a new application and run it, but the same issue occurred.

After seeing some feedback that more details are required I'm including the following:

1. The issues occurred on simulator
2. No messages in console/logs
3. Flutter doctor has 0 issues
4. When I used flutter run -v, it ends up stuck on the following

```
/Users/taruneswar/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-3.5.1/
[        ] Found plugin cloud_firestore_web at
/Users/taruneswar/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-2.8.10/
[        ] Found plugin firebase_core at
/Users/tarun/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/
[        ] Found plugin firebase_core_web at
/Users/tarun/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-1.7.3/
[   +8 ms] executing: [/Users/tarun/Documents/Front-end App Development/afg/macos/]
/usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -list -project Runner.xcodeproj
[   +6 ms] <- compile package:afg/main.dart
```

Comment: Simulator or device? Any messages in the console/logs? Have you tried inserting `print()` calls to narrow down where it is getting stuck?

Comment: you need to say some informations like flutter doctor and etc...

Comment: @ChuckBatson I included more information about the problem in the post.

Comment: @TarunEswar Try opening `Runner.xcodeproj` in Xcode and building/running from there. That may yield more info about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution besides updating Flutter to latest, Flutter clean routine and pod clean,

- Disable developer mode on the physical device
- Restart iPhone
- Delete the app if already installed (step 1 was required)
- Run in Flutter